# How to manipulate a function (Append/Prepend) multiple times?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, syntax, functional-style

I'm having trouble trying to manipulate a function in a type of "loop" format. Essentially what I want to do is be able to manipulate the amount of `Append` functions I use. For example:

```
data={3,4,5,1,5,2,4}

Append[data,0]={3,4,5,1,5,2,4,0}

Append[Append[data,0],0]={3,4,5,1,5,2,4,0,0}

Append[Append[Append[data,0],0],0]={3,4,5,1,5,2,4,0,0,0}
```

and so on...

I was wondering if there was an easy way to manipulate the number of `Append/Prepend` functions I use to that it is as simple as typing `1` or `2` into a line of code to get the number of `Append/Prepend` functions I apply to that particular dataset.

Thanks!

Comment: See `Nest`, but here `PadRight` looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4};

ArrayPad[data, {0, 3}]
```

or

```
{##, Sequence[0, 0, 0]} & @@ data
```

give

> {3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0}

Prepending:

```
ArrayPad[data, {3, 0}, x]
```

> {x, x, x, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4}

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome - thanks for acceptance

Answer (score 1):

```
Nest[Append[#, 0] &, data, 3]
```

switch to `Prepend` for the equivalent result.